# query_post causes the posts to be loaded twice on load more posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts

I am using query_post to randomize the posts in a custom post type. However this causes the posts to be loaded reloaded when i load more posts in.

Below is my code:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand'); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
          <div id="artistWrap">
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-lg-4 work">
                    <div class="innerWrapper">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));   ?>
                        </a>

                        <h2>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h2>                           
                    </div>
                </article><!-- #post-## -->

            <?php endwhile; ?> 
          </div>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

If i remove query_posts and just use the have_posts it doesn't load the posts in twice, but doesn't randomize it.

---

Update:

I have tried changing it to use wp_query and I still get the same problem with it loading in duplicate posts.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( orderby => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'artist' ) ); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
          <div id="artistWrap">
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-lg-6 work">
                    <div class="innerWrapper">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));   ?>
                        </a>

                        <h2>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </h2>                           
                    </div>
                </article><!-- #post-## -->

            <?php endwhile; ?> 
          </div>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: `query_post()` shouldn't be used overall, see [the tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-posts?sort=votes) for questions on the topic.

Comment: I have updated it to use wp_query and I still get the same problem.

Comment: if you want to modify the main query, you should be using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), not creating new queries in the template.